# How to programmatically scroll the horizontal scrollbar to left or right on holding Shift key in VB.Net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am new to VB.Net and I am trying out way to scroll the UI horizontally on using Shift key.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, or ASP.NET?

Comment: Then what type of control do you want to scroll?

Comment: This is using WPF

Comment: @ShrutiKatare Consider include the control's xaml you would like to implement scrolling.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I did not exactly get what you are mentioning. 

I am currently using PreviewMouseWheel="Window_PreviewMouseWheel" in xaml file and the method "Window_PreviewMouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseWheelEventArgs)" will handle the on shift+scroll activity. If there is any other way as well please suggest.